# how to print the database content on a desired page?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. I want to print the database content that is stored in my database dynamically on the desired page. I tried but an error appears everytime i.e;( undefined variable:). I just want to print whatever content I store in my database table dynamically.

My code is here:

My model name is:gallery

My routes:

```
Route::get('/gallery/list' ,[
  'uses'=>'gallerycontroller@viewgallerylist',
  'as'=>'viewgallery'
]);

Route::post('/gallery/save' ,[
  'uses'=>'gallerycontroller@savegallery',
  'as'=>'savegallery'
]);
```

My controller:

```
public function viewgallerylist()
  {
    $galleries = gallery::all();
    return view('gallery')->with('galleries', $galleries);
   }
   public function savegallery(Request $request)
    {
        $gallery1=$request['gallery_name'];


  $gallery=new gallery();
  $gallery->name=$gallery1;
  $gallery->save();
  return redirect()->route('viewgallery');
   }
```

My desired page:

```
 <form  method="post" action="{{ route('savegallery') }}">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="gallery_name">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="upl">Create+</button>
      <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
      </form>

 @foreach($galleries as $gallery)
<p>{{ $gallery->name }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: what is your `gallery` model name ?

Comment: my model name is gallery

Comment: and your desired page is 'gallery.blade.php' ? inside resources\views

Comment: yes exactly,  my gallery file is inside resources\views

Comment: Undefined variable: what variable? Laravel usually gives to you the name

Comment: undefined variable:galleries. this is an error which i get each time

Comment: if you replace  `return view('gallery')->with('galleries', $galleries);` to 
`return view('gallery',compact('galleries'));`
it's still not working?

Comment: it is still not working... @Dmitry

Comment: Have you: use App\Gallery; in your GalleryController, Gallery is the model name, I tried your Code and it works

Comment: yes, i use it in my controller... but, it doesn,t works

Comment: problem is that i want to show the content on the same page where i have a form. if i send the content on the other page it is working but not on the same page

Comment: As I said it works in the same page as the form, I have changed this line $gallery1= $request['gallery_name']; to $gallery1=$request->get('gallery_name'); in the controller perhaps this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most model Classes will have a capital letter. Are you sure your Model isn't called Gallery instead of gallery?

which means that you need to call `Gallery::all()` in your controller and make sure `use App\Gallery;` is at the top of your page.

```
public function viewgallerylist()
      {
        $galleries = Gallery::all();
        return view('gallery')->with('galleries', $galleries);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your model.... please provide a larger view

```
Route::get('/' ,[
  'uses'=>'gallerycontroller@viewgallerylist',
  'as'=>'viewgallery'
]);

Route::post('/' ,[
  'uses'=>'gallerycontroller@savegallery',
  'as'=>'savegallery'
]);
```